# cassandra support of where clause on non primay key column in materialized view

Tags: cassandra, datastax

We are designing table in cassandra which has the following schema :-

```
customeruuid,assetuuid,activation_status,createdtime

PK(customeruuid,assetuuid)
```

We need to support searching usecase where we need to list all assetuuid for particular customer with where clause on activation_status column.There could be millions of assets for customer.I did research on web and found that we could create an materialized view over this table. I am trying it out using following cql:

> CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW myiew1 AS    SELECT customeruuid,agentuuid,activation_status
>     FROM temp   WHERE customeruuid IS NOT NULL AND
>   agentuuid IS NOT NULL     PRIMARY KEY ( customeruuid, agentuuid );

I wanted to include where clause on activaiton_status column in select query but I am not able to do it. Does latest versions of cassandra supports such kind of operation or Do we have other alternative to solve this problem maybe by changing data modelling?

Comment: To do the `WHERE` on this data you need to put necessary columns into primary key of materialized view... And you're using OSS Cassandra or DSE?

Comment: We are using DSE. I tried putting this column in primary key but still facing issue

Comment: it's really depends on your requirements - how often this data is accessed, what is the latency required, etc., but look to use DSE Search to perform this task.

Comment: This is going to be frequently accessed, by the way activation_status column is enum, Can I create secondary index on this column?